# Execute and set parameters on a PowerShell script file

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, remedy

I am trying to run a ps1 file sending one paramter. This script is to unlock account on AD.

My ps1 file is:

```
Param([string]$user="")
Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter {mail -like "$user"} |
    Unlock-ADAccount |
    Sync-ADObject -Destination "AZUDCMO01"
```

And I called it using:

```
PS C:\Users\fornecedor.bmc01> .\bmc_unlock_ad.ps1 "andreza.perez@grupomoura.com"
```

No error is returned, but the account is still locked.

Anyone tried this way to unlock accounts?

Comment: Does `Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -like "$user"}` actually return a result? Because without wildcards the expression `mail -like "$user"` does the same as `mail -eq "$user"`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't want to use the `-Properties *` parameter at all. All you need is to get an ADUser object with enough properties to be able to send it through the pipeline.
`Get-ADUser` returns more than enough properties for that.

Having said that, You are piping from the `Unlock-ADAccount` cmdlet to the `Sync-ADObject` cmdlet, but...
according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/unlock-adaccount?view=win10-ps), the `Unlock-ADAccount` cmdlet by default does not return anything. For that part you need to add the parameter `-PassThru`.

Try this:

```
Param([string]$user="")

Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -like "$user"} |
    Unlock-ADAccount -PassThru |
    Sync-ADObject -Destination "AZUDCMO01"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I did the first test from cmd calling the ps1 file. Does not work. When I run the command from PS Console, it works. The command is ok, but whe it starts from DOS don't run.

Comment: @Barcat That depends on HOW you run the powershell script from a commandbox. If you try that using the syntax in your question, then indeed it will not work. Use `PS C:\Users\fornecedor.bmc01> powershell.exe -File "PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT" "andreza.perez@grupomoura.com"`. I don't know why you don't simply run it from within PowerShell though..

Comment: I would like to run from powershell, but it is a process that start on a thirdy-part-application. This app can run command send parameters to a file, so I use the ps1 file and the command line to call it and pass the username

Comment: @Barcat Alrighty then. You should be able to do it using the syntax I used in my comment.